# Use get url parameter in sql sent with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I can successfully send post data with ajax and get data into mysql database. However I can't display  when I use POST parameter in sql statement. İf I remove POST parameter from sql, data perfectly display where it should be.

What am I missing? Here what I've got.. thanks

```
**index.php**

<form method="POST" id="ask1">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group" >
        <textarea name="content" ></textarea>
     
      </div>
      

      <div class="form-group" >
        <input type="hidden"  name="service" value ="<?php echo ''.htmlentities($_GET["service"]).''  ?> ">
        
    
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

      </div>
    </form>

      <div><span id="message" ></span></div>
      <div id="display_message" ></div>
```

```
**ask.php**
$service = $_POST['service'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM ask WHERE comment_id = '0' and
service='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$service)."' ";

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
foreach($result as $row)
{


 $output .= '

<div class="panel-body" style="font-size:12px;">"'.$row["name"].'"</div>

 ';

 $output .= get_reply_comment($conn, $row["id"]);
}

echo $output;
```

```
Ajax 

<script>
load_comment();

 function load_comment()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"ask.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_message').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
</script>
```

Comment: your code is opened to SQL injections. Use parameters in your sql query

Comment: It's 2021, how are people still using real escape string instead of prepared statements

Comment: Have you looked at what is in the post variable at all?

Comment: thanks  Giacomo M. noted it